# no @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifiers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm new in iOS development, and i'm looking for some help on my UITableView issue.

Well, i was studying everything about the UITableView code, and, during the development, when i'm trying to reuse the identifier (in case that there's no cell to create on the interface), the XCode shows the message:

"No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:"

There's the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell ==nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }
```

Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

should be

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

you should allocate a `UITableViewCell`  not `UITableView`  like what you've done here.

```
   //should be **UITableViewCell**
      cell = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
```

and dont forget to return it later.

```
return cell;
```

Comment: So... `initWithStyle` doesn't complain despite that you alloc a `UITableView` instead of a `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: @Alladinian I think what you meant is initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: , it is a method declared in UITableViewCell, it returns an initialized UITableViewCell,

Comment: @Alladinian thats a compiler error, I assume the OP discovered that himself , and thank for pointing it out. did not notice that allocation.

Comment: @janusfidel And that's exactly the **title** of the question. Anyway, I was just surprised.

Comment: @Alladinian now Im suprised too. I did not notice that title until you pointed it out, so my original answer basically does not answer the real question. and now im wondering hows that original answer worked for the OP. he discovered it himself I guess. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. You are calling the method on a wrong class...
You'll just have to set the class & alloc a `UITableViewCell` instead of `UITableView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code instead of your code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Saved my day. 
Replaced my code - commented, with this code -and presto it worked. Not sure why though!!
but thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
//  static NSString *identifier = @"cell";
//  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIndentifier:@"cell"];

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```