# No visible @interface issue Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface

I am very new, as in I just started today with Objective C and I am getting this error every time I try to build my application.

```
Ticklist/RootTableViewController.m:69:36: No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the         selector 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:'
```

for these lines of code

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentfier = @"AnimalCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentfier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell =[[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentfier];
}
```

I am pretty good in java and I feel like this error is saying something along the lines of this variable hasn't been instantiated, even though I know this isn't a variable.

Im not asking for an answer verbatim, just a guidance in the right direction.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [no @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'initWithStyle:reuseIdentifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361434/no-interface-for-uitableview-declares-the-selector-initwithstylereuseidenti)

Comment: See also [No visible @interface for](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10387330)

Comment: You are correct, it is a duplicate. Sorry for that and thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewCell`not `UITableView`

---

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentfier];
```

not

```
cell = [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentfier];
```